# Как объявить, описать и проверить параметры командной строки в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, argv

В PowerShell есть замечательная возможность объявления параметров скрипта, их проверки, и автоматического описания. Записывается так:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    # Имя адаптера, обязательное, явно задавить имя параметра не нужно, определяется по позиции.
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [string]$AdapterName,

    # Целевые адреса в виде адрес/маска, например 192.168.72.0/24
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string[]]$TargetNets
)
```

А также с проверкой:

```
[ValidateSet("Tom","Dick","Jane")]
[String]$Name,

[ValidateRange(21,65)]
[Int]$Age,

[ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType 'Container'})]
[string]$Path
```

При ошибке ввода оболочка подскажет что и где и как должно быть. Подробнее [тут](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/jj554301.aspx) и [тут](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/15/simplify-your-powershell-script-with-parameter-validation.aspx). `Param` также применим к функциям.
Есть ли нечто подобное в Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Пример кода, который показывает как реализовать оба примера из вопроса, используя [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import pathlib


def valid_dir(path):
    path = pathlib.Path(path)
    try:
        if path.is_dir():
            return path
    except OSError:
        pass
    raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('%s is not a valid directory' % (path,))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('adapter-name')
parser.add_argument('targetnets', nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('--name', choices={"Tom", "Dick", "Jane"})
parser.add_argument('--age', type=int, choices=range(21, 65))
parser.add_argument('--path', type=valid_dir)
print(parser.parse_args())
```

См. [directory path types with argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11416062/4279).

Пример запуска:

```
$ python3 . lo 10.0.3.0/24 127.0.0.0/8 --name Tom --age 22 --path .
Namespace(adapter-name='lo', age=22, name='Tom', path=PosixPath('.'),
          targetnets=['10.0.3.0/24', '127.0.0.0/8'])
```

Comment: А почему raise не внутри блока except? Просто интересно.

Comment: @insolor: цель подчеркнуть для читателя: или `path` возвращается или ошибка выбрасывается (нет неявного `return None`).

Answer (score 2):

Существует множество библиотек, которые позволяют описывать/проверять параметры командной строки как часть их работы, например, уже упомянутый модуль [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) из стандартной библиотеки, простой [`docopt`](http://docopt.org/), ориентированный на создание стандартного интерфейса, [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org/3/), ориентированный на поддержку произвольного CLI интерфейса.

Парсер командной строки задаётся в [`docopt`](http://docopt.org/), используя стандартный язык для примеров использования, первый фрагмент транслируется в:

```
Usage: ваша-программа <adapter-name> <nets>...
```

Это *буквальное* описание говорит `docopt`, что `ваша-программа` имеет два обязательных параметра и второй параметр это список (одно или более значений), [живой пример](http://try.docopt.org/?doc=Usage%3A+program+%3Cadapter-name%3E+%3Cnets%3E...&argv=a+b+c).

Вот полный пример кода c [`docopt`](http://docopt.org/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Print adapter ips that belong to given networks.

Usage: ваша-программа <adapter-name> <nets>...
       ваша-программа -h | --help | --version

Arguments:
  adapter-name  Имя адаптера
  nets          Адреса в виде адрес/маска, например 192.168.72.0/24
"""
import ipaddress
import docopt  # $ pip install docopt
import netifaces  # $ pip install netifaces

def parse_ip(ip_string):
    """Parse ip string such as '10.0.3.0' returning None on error."""
    try:
        return ipaddress.ip_address(ip_string)
    except ValueError:
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = docopt.docopt(__doc__, version='ваша-программа 1.0')
    try:
        networks = [ipaddress.ip_network(network_spec)
                    for network_spec in args['<nets>']]
        ifaddresses = [netifaces.ifaddresses(args['<adapter-name>'])[family]
                       for family in [netifaces.AF_INET, netifaces.AF_INET6]]
    except ValueError as e:
        raise docopt.DocoptExit(str(e))
    adapter_ips = [parse_ip(ip['addr']) for ips in ifaddresses for ip in ips]
    # find intersection
    print(*[ip for ip in filter(None, adapter_ips)
            for network in networks if ip in network])
```

Пример запуска:

```
$ ваша-программа lo 10.0.3.0/24 127.0.0.0/8
127.0.0.1
$ ваша-программа lxcbr0 10.0.3.0/24 127.0.0.0/8
10.0.3.1
```

Спецификация, из которой [`docopt`](http://docopt.org/) создаёт парсер для командной строки, приведена в `__doc__` (строка наверху модуля).

Проверка в сам [`docopt`](http://docopt.org/) не входит. Как показывает пример, это не всегда нужно: `ipaddress.ip_network()`, `netifaces.ifaddresses()` выбросят `ValueError`, если неправильные значения указать.

По желанию, можно установить разные проверяльщики. Вот [пример кода с `schema`](https://github.com/docopt/docopt/blob/master/examples/validation_example.py).

---

Второй фрагмент c использованием [`schema`](https://github.com/keleshev/schema):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Usage: prog.py [--name=<name> --age=<n> --path=<folder>]"""
import pathlib
import docopt   # $ pip install docopt
from schema import And, Or, Schema, SchemaError, Use  # $ pip install schema


def valid_dir(path):
    try:
        return path.is_dir()
    except OSError:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = docopt.docopt(__doc__)
    schema = Schema({
        '--name': Or(None, "Tom", "Dick", "Jane",
                     error='--name can be only Tom, Dick, or Jane'),
        '--age': Or(None, And(Use(int), lambda n: 21 <= n < 65),
                    error='--age should be in [21, 65) range'),
        '--path': Or(None, And(Use(pathlib.Path), valid_dir),
                     error='--path should be a valid folder')})
    try:
        args = schema.validate(args)
    except SchemaError as e:
        raise docopt.DocoptExit(str(e))

    print(args)
```

Пример:

```
$ python prog.py  --path . --age 21
```

Результат:

```
{'--age': 21,
 '--name': None,
 '--path': PosixPath('.')}
```

Пример кода без использования [`schema`](https://github.com/keleshev/schema):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Usage: prog.py [--name=<name> --age=<n> --path=<folder>]"""
import pathlib
import docopt  # $ pip install docopt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = docopt.docopt(__doc__)
    if (args['--name'] is not None and
            args['--name'] not in {"Tom", "Dick", "Jane"}):
        raise docopt.DocoptExit('--name can be only Tom, Dick, or Jane')
    if args['--age'] is not None:
        try:
            args['--age'] = int(args['--age'])
            if args['--age'] not in range(21, 65):
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            raise docopt.DocoptExit('--age should be in [21, 65) range')
    if args['--path'] is not None:
        args['--path'] = pathlib.Path(args['--path'])
        try:
            if not args['--path'].is_dir():
                raise ValueError
        except (ValueError, OSError):
            raise docopt.DocoptExit('--path should be a valid folder')

    print(args)
```

Результат тот же.

В данном простом случае, где код ничего кроме проверки аргументов не делает, ограничения на аргументы простые и сами аргументы являются независимыми, вариант с декларативной проверкой аргументов (со `schema`) выглядит более предпочтительным по сравнению с явным кодом на Питоне, но [аргумент, представленный по ссылке в вопросе,](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/15/simplify-your-powershell-script-with-parameter-validation.aspx) является спорным. Это аргумент людей, которые верят, что отсутствие обязательных статических меток для типов в Питоне (но [см. `typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)), должно приводить к куче `if isinstance(arg1, type1): raise ValueError`, чтобы скомпенсировать работу компилятора в статических языках. Фактически, много вызовов `isinstance()` не одобряется в Питоне и обычно можно найти лучше решения в зависимости от конкретной задачи.

В обычном коде в любом случае, если вы хотите использовать значения, то вам придётся их преобразовывать к нужному виду и обрабатывать соответствующие ошибки по месту использования, чтобы избежать race, например, директория может быть удалена после проверки, но до использования ([LBYL vs. EAFP](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/21/robust-exception-handling)). Использование инструментов по описанию требований к параметрам либо может быть недостаточно для более сложных случаев или же в лучшем случае такое описание будет эквивалентно Python коду только с менее привычным синтаксисом (если вы можете описать любые требования, то ваш язык описаний Turing complete и у нас уже есть приятный Turing complete язык и он называется Python и почему бы его и не использовать напрямую, чтобы выразить требования).

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/argparse.html)

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument("foo", ..., required=True)
parser.parse_args()
```

Ответ на [английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188467/how-to-check-if-an-argument-from-commandline-has-been-set).
*P.S. Кто-то отвечал, но удалился...*

Comment: `required=True` не нужно для `"foo"` (аргумент и так обязателен по умолчанию). Только для опций, таких как `--bar`, нужно явно `required=True`, если вам нужна обязательная "опция".