# Как указать скрипту путь до файла в Python?

Tags: python

Мой скрипт должен принимать на вход путь до текстового файла и выводить в консоль сколько захотите самых популярных слов в этом файле в порядке убывания частоты. Он работает, но только если указать название файла.  Но если у меня его нет?
**Подскажите пожалуйста что почитать и где найти ответ?**

```
from collections import Counter
    import re
    number = int(input("Введите число самых популярных слов, которое вы хотите вывести на экран: "));
    with open('Другой путь.txt', 'r+') as file:
        words = re.findall(r'\w+', file.read().lower())
        ten_most_frequent_words = Counter(words).most_common(number)
        print(ten_most_frequent_words)
```

Результатом выполнения кода будет подобный результат:

`[('и', 1728), ('в', 1576), ('не', 1360), ('он', 1190), ('что', 1100), ('я', 1066), ('на', 1000), ('его', 690), ('это', 688), ('с', 663)]`

Comment: Можете добавить ещё один input для ввода пользователем пути. Или доставать из [аргументов командой строки](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

Comment: Эээм... если я вас правильно понял: просто вместо имени файла поставьте `input()`

Comment: `Но если у меня его нет?` - чего нет? Файла или имени файла?

Comment: Ну мой скрипт умеет работать только с файлом 'Другой путь.txt'

Comment: Вопрос не ясен: вы хотите что бы пользователь мог сам указать файл? Или чего-то другого?

Comment: Владимир, именно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете указать аргументы для скрипта прямо в командной строке:

```
$ ваш-скрипт /путь/к/файл.txt
```

К примеру, чтобы прочитать слова из файлов, переданные  как аргументы командной строки ([`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv)) в терминале  или прочитать слова со стандартного ввода, [можно использовать `fileinput` модуль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/718506/23044).

Чтобы распознать более сложные опции можно [`argparse` модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse) использовать. [Как объявить, описать и проверить параметры командной строки в Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/464718/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Вместо:

```
with open('Другой путь.txt', 'r+') as file:
```

вставьте:

```
filename = input("Введите путь к файлу: ")
with open(filename, 'r+') as file:
```

Comment: Спасибо! Самый простой вариант в принципе.