# Как в python разобрать параметры командной строки?

Tags: python-3.x

По аналогии как в командной строке

> ftp -a -A

получить значения -A и -a.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: @Alban Спасибо !!

Comment: http://click.pocoo.org еще один вариант, сделанный с заботой о программистах.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как объявить, описать и проверить параметры командной строки в Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464718/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте для этого модуль [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) из стандартной библиотеки. Это упростит обработку параметров командной строки, и сделает разбор аргументов более консистентным - то есть всё будет выглядеть так, как и у других программ.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Просто какой-то пример")
parser.add_argument('-a', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-A', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()

print('a =', args.a)
print('A =', args.A)
```

Больше примеров смотрите в документации. Некоторые фишки, поддерживаемые модулем:

- Автоматическая генерация справки по ключу `-h` или `--help`.
- Возможность сокращения ключей (можно написать `--he` и получить справку).
- Задание различных типов аргументов у ключей, валидация.
- Определение подкоманд (как в Git `git commit` и др. и проч.)